# Difference between "keep somebody from doing" and "prevent somebody from doing"

Tags: difference

Do these sentences have a different meaning ?

> You kept me from having dinner by keeping me waiting for you.
>
> You prevented me from having dinner by keeping me waiting for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sentence have a similar meaning in terms of **not having dinner at a given time**, however there is a difference

> You **kept** me from having dinner by keeping me waiting for you.

potentially has two different interpretations, 1) it could mean you were **delayed** having dinner in the sense that one was **kept** (held) and then subsequently **released**

> You **kept** me from having dinner **at 6:00pm** by keeping me waiting for you.
>   You **delayed** me from having dinner **on time** by keeping me waiting for you.

or 2) it could mean you were **stopped** from having dinner

> You **kept** me from having **any** dinner **last night** by keeping me waiting for you.
>   You **stopped** me from having **any** dinner **last night** by keeping me waiting for you.

The ambiguity is usually resolved by the surrounding context.

Using **prevented** is unambiguous, meaning the event **did not happen**

> You **prevented** me from having dinner by keeping me waiting for you.
>   You **stopped** me from having **any** dinner by keeping me waiting for you.
>
> Snuffing out cigarettes will help **prevent** forest fires.
>   Taking vitamin C will help **prevent** colds.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to definitions they are synonymous.

However in conversation, it is implied that *kept* **delayed** your meal, whereas *prevented* did precisely that: you did not eat dinner.

Comment: I'm a native English speaker - well the American version of English anyway ;-) // I disagree with your differentiation. To me both sentences imply that you went without a "proper" dinner. It is ambiguous if you may have eaten something much after the expected mealtime such as some sort of snack before bed.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) You kept me from having dinner by keeping me waiting for you.
>
> (2) You prevented me from having dinner by keeping me waiting for you.

Both sentences mean the same thing. You went without a "proper" dinner. You may have eaten something afterwards like a snack before bed.

A English speaker would certainly understand both sentences, and both sentences could have conceivable been spoken. However I don't particularly like either sentence.

The first sentence uses kept and keeping. It just seems awkward. Better phrasing would be:

> You kept me waiting, so I missed dinner.

The second proposed sentence seems awkward too. I assume that the sentence is trying to express righteous indignation for having been stood up. "Prevented me" and "keeping me" have the wrong connotation since it was the speaker's decision to wait for what seems like an exceptionally long time. So if the speaker transfers all the blame in such a manner then the speaker's objection seems overstated and it makes the speaker seem hotheaded.

> I missed dinner because I waited for you.

Answer (score 0):

"To keep someone from doing" and "to prevent someone from doing" are just variants. "to prevent" is Latin, "to keep" is more everyday language.